# iOS popToRootViewControllerAnimated what method will be called after?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a strange problem in my app. When I'm pressed backButton from UINavigationController I trying to handle it with `-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` in a next way:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated] ;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];
}
```

After it I want do some code in `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` of my rootTableViewController. But it's seems like that method wasn't called, but my controller
is changed to root(visual at least ). Have you any idea what I do wrong & how to resolve it?

Comment: how you navigate from rootTableViewController to other controller whether using segues?

Comment: what is backButton here is it your custom UIButton or default navigation item..?

Comment: UINavigationController -> rootTableViewController - >firstTableViewController -> secondTableViewController.
backButton - its default UINavigationController button